# Read both underlying and uncommitted transaction data

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions

Using SQL Server from .NET, is it possible (using the same or separate connections) to read both the underlying data as well as the as-yet uncommitted changes from another separate connection?

For example:

I have Connection1, which starts a transaction and inserts a record with Id == 1 into a table but doesn't commit it

From Connection2, I would like to read the table without that row existing

From Connection2 or Connection3, I would like to read the table with the row existing.

Comment: gbn has the right answer. But I have to warn you - I went down this road a few years ago for performance reasons and it ended up causing nothing but trouble. If you're trying to speed up a query spend more time on the query and let SQL Server do the right thing with locks.

Comment: Why? Each connection shouldn't care about other transactions..

Comment: It was to implement [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725512/) but I've gone with a different solution now anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable dirty reads aka READ UNCOMMITTED

Edit:

To read both sets of data you'd need a combination of "snapshot isolation" in one connection and "read uncommitted" in another.

YMMV. It isn't something...

1. I've tried
2. See a use for
3. I'd have confidence in

Comment: I'm aware of READ UNCOMMITTED, which will allow me to read the uncommitted changes, but I think maybe my question wasn't clear, so I've updated it. The question is can I access BOTH underlying and uncommitted changes for the SAME transaction.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but I didn't go ahead with what I asked in my question in the end - it just seemed too flaky.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can review uncommitted data within the current session like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    ID int not null
);

INSERT INTO TestTable(ID) values(1);
INSERT INTO TestTable(ID) values(2);
INSERT INTO TestTable(ID) values(3);

SELECT * FROM TestTable;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TestTable(ID) values(4);
    INSERT INTO TestTable(ID) values(5);

    --Although the transaction has not commited you can still see the records inserted from within the current sessions scope.
    SELECT * FROM TestTable;


COMMIT TRANSACTION

DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

Now suppose you where to open another connection that you wanted to be able to see this uncommited data. You could do so at the query level by using the [NOLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) query hint. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WITH(NOLOCK)
```